# Using two instances of Bus and handling events from both the instances

Tags: nservicebus

In our ecosystem we want to use two Rabbit brokers for NSericeBus transport.

I observed with a spike, that I am able to get messages from both the brokers by instantiating two bus instances (on worker). No other change was required for the handlers.

If this approach is ok for integration scenarios (with other systems) in case other systems are using a different Rabbit Broker?  Or in case if we want to use a additional Rabbit broker for failover  (with some custom code to switch the publish/send to the available node)?

Comment: Will [this article](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/rabbitmq/cluster) help?

Comment: Thanks Sean. We are not in a position to use clustered RabbitMQ brokers, but instead two independent RabbitMQ brokers.